# Inkcanvas StrokeErasing event

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas, stroke

I'm using an [Inkcanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610988.aspx) at my solution.
So I want to delete after user confirm, like this...

XAML:

```
<InkCanvas Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="ink"  StrokeErasing="ink_StrokeErasing" />
```

C#:

```
private void ink_StrokeErasing(object sender, InkCanvasStrokeErasingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Delete this stroke?", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

After that, I can see the messagebox twice, :(
This Wonder how that happened. Please let me konw about this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this error and used ink.EditingMode = `InkCanvasEditingMode.EraseByStroke;`

This only triggers the message box once.

When I use `ink.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.Select;` and press delete after selecting a stroke, the messagebox is not shown.

Then I used `ink.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.EraseByPoint;` and that caused the message box to appear multiple times because it is triggered for every single point of the stroke you are deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks emo. Actually I used "InkCanvasEditingMode.EraseByStroke" and I have to use this value. :( 
Anyway I guess the problem is mouse focus. I changed my code like this...

```
private void ink_StrokeErasing(object sender, InkCanvasStrokeErasingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released) { e.Cancel = true; return; }

    if (MessageBox.Show("Delete this stroke?", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

It works fine :) I suspect that this is a bug.